# What XXXX0.localstorage-journal is used for?

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, local-storage, file-format

As far as I know, the W3C doesn't have a specification for implementing localStorage, so I want to know how does Chrome implement localStorage.

I found lots of XXXX0.localstorage-journal and XXXX0.localstorage files in the folder:C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage.

I know XXXX0.localstorage is just a .sqlite file, but I am curious what XXXX0.localstorage-journal is used for?

I have googled many times but I couldn't find this things, so hope someone give me some hints .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rollback journal](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#rollback) contains old data to allow a transaction to be rolled back.